# How to match a string that doesnt contain a pattern

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I am trying to write a regex template that matches all the strings that doesn't contain a certain template.

E.g.:

Matches:

```
This is my friend. He is very nice.
```

in

```
This is my friend. He is very nice.
```

but doesn't match anything in :

```
  This is my friend John Michaels Fredrickson. He is very nice.
```

Because it contains something like this: **([A-Z][a-z]+\s?){3}**

Comment: Sounds more like a fulltext search than a task for regex...

Comment: It's not really clear to me, what you are asking. If you have a string that matches with `if (regex.Match(s))`, simply invert the condition to have it not match: `if (!regex.Match(s))`

Comment: do you understand what `Contains` means.. since the words / pattern is in `This is my friend John Michaels Fredrickson. He is very nice.` Contains will be true.. best to read up on Contains and what it means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*?([A-Z][a-z]+\W){3}).*$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vK7mM9/1)